# How to Make material slider disabled

Tags: angular, material-design

I am using Angluar with material design, i am facing some issue, so the question is how to make material slider disabled on some specific value

```
<mat-slider min="1" max="5" step="0.5" value="{{myVar}}"></mat-slider>
```

I need to show it on my component with some specific value that comes from db, and can not be changed until it will change into db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you can just use `disabled` as like this

```
<mat-slider min="1" max="5" disabled  step="0.5" value="{{myVar}}"></mat-slider>
```

not big deal.

Answer (score 6):

So let us say you have a model that looks like this

```
export interface MyModel {
   someValue: number;
}
```

And you load it within your component using some service that calls your API. Just pass the condition via [disabled input](https://material.angular.io/components/slider/api#directives) to it.

```
<mat-slider [disabled]="myModel.someValue > 50" min="1" max="5" step="0.5" value="{{myVar}}"></mat-slider>
```

Comment: I think you didn't get it, i want it to be disabled always, for real just forgot about `disabled` stuff. I am getting some value from db just for view. Anyway thanks.

Comment: In your question you said  "[...]is how to make material slider disabled on some specific value[..]". So my answer is totally correct indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `style="pointer-events: none;"` will prevent the value from changing

```
<mat-slider style="pointer-events: none;" min="1" max="5" step="0.5" value="{{myVar}}" ></mat-slider>
```